# Version History in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I have List with 40+ fields in List and items are creating/updating with non-SharePoint UI.
When there is an update to list item, we just updating all the fields to SPListItem and calling item.Update().

Now customer requirement is to have field level tracking so that on every update, system should be intelligent to identify the only modified fields in list item.

Any idea on getting the summary of changes on each update?

I prefer to do this SharePoint object model

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? Are you looking for a way to turn on versions, or avoid setting fields to values that they already have, or something completely different?

Comment: I am looking for a way to get the summary of changes happened in my form from SPList

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [`SPListItem.Versions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.versions.aspx) property. From there, you can get access to [`SPListItemVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversion.aspx) objects that correspond to individual versions. This class provides you access to previous values of the item's fields.